# How to make actionscript interact with c++ in win32 window?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, winapi

I have a win32 window in which I have a child window which runs a swf. Thus i have a swf running inside my main win32 window created using c++. Now how can i make the events of flash(swf) appear in my c++ code. For example how can i send a string from my flash to c++ ?

Does `ExternalInterface` help in this regard ? If yes, then how can c++ recieve what flash sends ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will need to use `ExternalInterface`.  Take a look at [flash-to-directx](http://code.google.com/p/flash-to-directx/).  Look through their code and see how they pass the swf events and information to your c++ program.